# Customer and Order Sql Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

TSQL query to select all records from Customer that has an Order and also select all records from customer that does not have an Order. The table Customer contains a primary key of CustomerID. The table Order contains a primary key of OrderID and a foreign key of CustomerID.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why sign up for the course if you're not going to go to class?

Comment: So you only want customer records that have and don't have an order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solutions.

```
Select CustomerName
from Customer
Where pk_CustomerID IN
(
Select fk_CustomerID from Orders
INNER JOIN Customer
on Customer.pk_CustomerID=Orders.fk_CustomerID)
```

/* NOT IN instead of IN will give the other customers who doesn't have an Order */

Comment: @jero: I am sorry but those `pk_` and `fk_` prefixes gotta go.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
Select yourcustomerfields, yourorderfields
From Customer
Left join Orders on Customer.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
```